# Canvas with block display still has gap between div and canvas element

Tags: javascript, css, html, canvas

Open this and inspect element, you see that there's a gap between the canvas and the top.

How do I remove this gap?

```
<html>
<title>Canvas demo</title>
<body bgcolor="black" style="overflow: hidden">
<center>
    <div id="game_container">
        <canvas id="canvas" style= "width: 780px; height: 780px; cursor: none;">
        </canvas>
    </div>
</center>
</body>

<script>
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
canvas.style.display = 'block';
</script>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i guess its the that body giving default margin
try this

```
html,body,canvas{margin:0;padding:0;border:0;font-size: 100%;width:100%;height:100%;}
```

This should fix

Answer (score 0):

You can use a reset css for this case.

```
canvas {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
```